Httrack: mirror site locally including all resources
I want to create clone a remote, publicly accessible website using httrack.
I want to the site's structure to be preserved so I can simply move the mirror's directory to a local location on my own filesystem that I can serve locally using a local webserver.
Where I get stuck is that by default httrack doesn't download all assets.
So after mirroring the site and then navigating to the local version in my web browser, some js, css and other files are being fetched from remote sources.
How do I create a complete local mirror of a website, including all of the resources that it requires?

have you downloaded HTTRACK in your local pc. for both window and ubatu version are available at https://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html
you just run is after install and add
you can use this command for ubantu in terminal
httrack https://example.com/ -O /path/to/local

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
